# Why do WindowEvents work but SolutionEvents and TextEditorEvents don't?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am going off the list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx). I want to be notified when the solution or project changes. I started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765531/windowstate-change-event-in-visual-studio-extension) code and added to it.

```
    public void Watch()
    {
        DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
        dte.Events.SolutionEvents.Opened += SolutionEvents_Opened;
        dte.Events.TextEditorEvents.LineChanged += TextEditorEvents_LineChanged;
        dte.Events.WindowEvents.WindowMoved += WindowEvents_WindowMoved;
    }

    private void WindowEvents_WindowMoved(Window Window, int Top, int Left, int Width, int Height)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("1-->");
    }

    private void TextEditorEvents_LineChanged(TextPoint StartPoint, TextPoint EndPoint, int Hint)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("2-->");
    }

    private void SolutionEvents_Opened()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("3-->");
    }
```

But only WindowEvents_WindowMoved ever fires. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Keep references to Events http://stackoverflow.com/a/32600629/84507

Comment: I agree, this could easily be the issue. Please try and update with results.