# Visual Studio Extension - How to listen on Solution \ Project item selection change

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I Creating a Visual Studio Extension and I would like to listen when user selection item change or when current project selection change.

I try to listen - OnChange in SelectionEvents:

```
 var dte = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2;
 var dteEvents = dte.Events as Events2;
 var selectionEvents = dteEvents.SelectionEvents;
 selectionEvents.OnChange += SelectionEventsOnOnChange;
```

But the OnChange event doesn't fire.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600629/84507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
In short: DTE events are COM object and when you handle an event to this kind of objects in a local function the GC we remove there reference.
**Solution**: save a private member of the events object.

```
private DTE2 _dte2;
private Events2 _dteEvents;
private SelectionEvents _selectionEvents;

private void OnLoaded()
{
    _dte2 = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2;
    _dteEvents = _dte2.Events as Events2;
    _selectionEvents = _dteEvents.SelectionEvents;
    _selectionEvents.OnChange += SelectionEventsOnOnChange;
}
```

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, please mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)